# flexbox items - ignore margin bottom with stretch alignment

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In a set of flexbox items with 'stretch' alignment, when one item has a margin bottom the other items will expand to include that margin. Is there a way to create a flex layout where the items remain the same height even when a margin bottom is applied to one of the elements?

Demo:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
  
.flex div {
    padding: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 10px;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.flex div:first-child {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: apply padding to parent? or change alignment to flex-start

Comment: Why would you only apply it to one element if your intention was to add it to all?

Comment: @Pete it's a peculiar layout where i need to keep a row of wrapped flex items at their original height but use margins on a single item to create space between the rows

Comment: You're probably looking for "flexbox masonry" just google it.

Comment: @Pete so in a responsive wrapped flex layout that would probably mean using javascript to figure out which items to apply the margin to (all items in one row) which i was trying to avoid

Comment: @Pete a more accurate demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XBqabP trying to create space below the row dynamically

Comment: @Pete sorry, Pen updated: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XBqabP

Comment: ok I would do something like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZjoXvG and then add a media query in for when you go to 3 on a row and add that margin top back on to the 4th child (think that would be less than 440px;)

Comment: So `align-items:flex-start` is actually what you need...right? - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/wxjrpR

Comment: @Paulie_D flex start will mean columns aren't equal heights

Comment: But you don't want them equal heights...right?

Comment: Want them equal heights with 50px between rows

Comment: So how does flex-start not do that...see the codepen I provided.

Comment: @Pete Yeah, that's where I'm headed I think. I need the gap to occur when an element in a row is clicked so I'll probably use JS to figure out what row it's in and target all the items in that row

Comment: @Paulie_D https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GBdMGB vs https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZjoXvG

Comment: Oh...well the answer then is... **you can't** with pure CSS. You're gonna need javascript I suspect since rows aren't elements in flexbox. CSS-Grid could do that however.

Comment: @Paulie_D yeah, the question really just boiled down to if you can apply a margin on one flex item without affecting the height of the others. I would have expected padding to affect the others' height but not a margin